# How to write a list of file names to a .lst file using bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, php

I am new to linux and trying to work with bash commands within a PHP script that I'm attempting to write, I am needing to write each PDF file name from a directory that I'm iterating through using the DirectoryIterator () in PHP to a .lst file that I have sitting in another folder and have each file name listed on a new line in the text file.

The .lst file should look like this:

1.pdf 
2.pdf 
3.pdf 
...

I hope this makes sense.  Any HELP/DIRECTION would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I've come up with so far:

```
// Use the command line cp to copy each PDF file in the sourceDir to the destinationDir.
foreach ($srcDir as $entity) {

    /**
     * @var DirectoryIterator $entity
     */
    /*$result = rename($sourceDir . '/' . $entity->getFilename(), $destinationDir .'/' . $entity->getFileName());
    if(!$result)
    {
        throw Exception('Could not copy file ' . $entity->getFilename() . 'to destination directory ');
    }*/

    $cpString = 'cp ' . $sourceDir . '/' . $entity->getFilename() . ' ' . $destinationDir .'/' . $entity->getFileName() . ' 2<&1';
    passthru($cpString, $returnVar);

    if($entity->isFile() && strtoupper($entity->getExtension()) == 'PDF')
    {
        $cpString = 'cp ' . $sourceDir . '/' . $entity->getFilename() . ' ' . $destinationDir .'/' . $entity->getFileName();
        if ($counter = 1) {
            $catString = 'cat ' . $destinationDir . '/' . $batchNum . '.lst';
        }
        $cpString = ''
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: @grawity's answer below should be perfect. Is there some reason you _need_ to use bash commands?Are you also trying to copy the file somewhere?

Comment: Yes.  My boss wants me to the use the bash line commands within my PHP code that I become more familiar with them since I'm new to bash and PHP scripts.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Something like the `echo -n` option described in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/474581/57398) may help you.

Comment: @Melinda you and your boss should be aware that running shell code from PHP invites security holes, and should be done only when absolutely necessary. If they want you to practice shell, it should be where the consequences aren't as dire.

Comment: Great info.  Thanks for the heads up.  I'm sure he's aware just trying to help me understand how the bash commands help me in PHP or that is my understanding.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen("foo.lst", "w");

foreach ($srcDir as $entity)
    fwrite($fh, $entity->getFilename() . "\n");

fclose($fh);
```